# How can I alter url paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, because my controller is called listings, whenever I post a new listing it is for example domain.com/listings/listing-name however I would like it to be domain.com/businesses/listing-name instead.

How can I do this?

Current routes for this controller:

```
  resources :listings do
     member do
       post :leadcreate
       post :storycreate
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `path` option

```
resources :listings, :path => "businesses" do
end
```

If you also want to rename the route helpers, then

```
resources :listings, :path => "businesses", :as => "businesses" do
end
```